# How to get Error message text using xpath in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, gettext, webautomation

I am trying to get the error text from the below using XPath

`<p id="username-error" class="error-msg" role="alert" data-error="messages.INVALID_USERNAME">Sorry, we don't recognize this&nbsp;email.</p>`

here is my code:

`message = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username-error"]').text`

This piece of code is not returning anything. Kindly help me to get the error text such as "Sorry, we don't recognize this email."

Comment: As far as selenium is concerned without having the url, it will be difficult for community to get successful result from a live simulation based test. If you have that `<p>` tag data stored somewhere, you can still get data using web scraping techniques, but for selenium you need to provide us the URL

Answer (score 0):

A minor change in the XPath has fixed the problem.

`message = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-error="messages.INVALID_USERNAME"]').text`